# Function Overloading in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, overloading, dynamic-binding

C experts as per my understanding Objective-C is a dynamic binding language which not allowed to overload any method in a class.

But one thing irritating me if I write two methods with the same name but a different number of parameters list like:

```
 // Which is not allowed in objective-c

 -(void)updateValue:(int)intVal{

  } 

 -(void)updateValue:(float)floatVal{

  }
```

But the second case which Objective-C allowing is:

```
 // Allowed in Objective-C

 -(void)updateValue:(int)intVal{

   }

 -(void)updateValue:(float)floatVal :(int)intVal{

   }
```

Although both cases are Method overloading.

Now my question is why the second case is allowed.

Is the method with two params in the second case changing the Method Name ? or something else ?

Kindly explain.

Comment: Never write `-(void)updateValue:(float)floatVal :(int)intVal`. At least, write `-(void)updateValue:(float)floatVal andSomething:(int)intVal`. Else, the signature are `-updateValue:`, `-updateValue::`(when there is no param introduction), and `-updateValue:andSomething:`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is the method with two params in the second case changing the Method Name ?

Yes. A method name is the compound of all its parameter prefixes including the colons. So your two methods are `updateValue:` and `updateValue::`.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)updateValue:(int)intVal
  {
  } 

 -(void)updateValue:(float)floatVal
  {
  }
```

This is not allowed as when user call updateValue with parameter then because of type casting the value can change and ambiguous method is show.

```
 -(void)updateValue:(int)intVal
   {
   }

  -(void)updateValue:(float)floatVal :(int)intVal
  {
  }
```

is allowed as parameter count is different so compiler knows which method to call and when so ambiguous method call is not their